# Maven and Eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a set of Eclipse plugins:

[image]

that I'd like to build using maven.

**My question is:** since there is no one single entry point, how do I use maven to organise the building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a project that have all modules( your projects ) and then build this project that actually will build all of your plugins.

For more info please refer to [creating a maven project on eclipse](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html) and
[create a multimodule project with maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html)